# Resources are accessible only on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a pretty large application with lots of video resources

I have them in a folder called video and they are marked as resources in the build settings.

On the simulator (all of them) I can access them using

```
 NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSURL *vidURL  = [bundle URLForResource:videoName withExtension:@"mov"];
```

but when installing the app or debugging it on a real device the **vidURL** is always **NULL**

Any idea what is going on ?

I've tested on two different devices with two different os versions.

Comment: Do you have the same case in `videoName` as the actual file. Devices are case-sensitive, and the simulator is not. Maybe the file is named `MyVideo.MOV`?

Comment: Yes, all lower case.

Comment: If you log the bundle URL or path for both simulator and device are your resources in the same relative location to it on each platform?

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm getting null on the real device so I can't see the path the files are at in the first place to be able to compare it to the simulator's path

Comment: Do you mean null for the `bundle`?  (If not, I was suggesting inspecting `[bundle bundlePath]`.)

Comment: the bundle isn't null, and [bundle bundlePath] returns two different paths on the different platforms, but that is expected.

still unable to "find" the videos inside the bundle

Comment: I'm mad at myself now, It turned out that the folder itself was capitalised for some reason.

@PhillipMills thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that it is a case sensitivity bug.

The folder was **Video** instead of **video**